# Using object loop and array loop in just one line

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, coffeescript

```
 15   for key,value of options
 16     for item in value
 17       console.log item
```

Guys, i have this piece of code and i would like to change it to use just one line, is possible?

I know that coffeescript allow using one line for several things, but i didn't found one for object + array looping.

Thanks.

Comment: Well, coffeescript don't allow to remove indentation and spaces, otherwise any complex code could have been written in one-line

Comment: The question is: Is it *better* to write it on one line?

Comment: @Tomalak OR _loop over nested object in one line_

Comment: nop.. is how to write in one line

Comment: Why would you want to write it in one line? There are plenty of horrible ways to do so, but unless you have a real, practical reason to want exactly one line… don’t?

Comment: @user I'm sorry, this question is off-topic on StackOverflow. This site exist to solve a different category of problems.

Comment: why? i want improve the coffee..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you can doesn't mean you should. It's not horrible but two `for` in the same line, that's too much for me:

```
console.log item for item in value for key, value of options
```

The two lines version is more readable:

```
for key, value of options
    console.log item for item in value
```